# How to properly load custom package in Laravel?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

How to load Facebook  class or any other non Laravel package in my controllers in Laravel 5. I have installed Facebok SDK - in my composer.json:

```
"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0"
```

In my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


use Facebook;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

      // this fails
      $fb = new Facebook();

    }
}
```

This generates error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Facebook' not found
```

How to load Facebook package or any other custom packages in my controllers?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it here is the correct way to instantiate a Facebook class:

Wrong:

```
$fb = new Facebook(....)
```

Correct:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(....)
```